# Set response format html Message in WCF C#

Tags: c#, wcf, format, message

There is a WCF-service in C#:

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
class SubscriptionService : ISubscriptionService
{        
    public Message Help(Message m)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
        return new WebHttpHelpPageMessage();
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
interface ISubscriptionService
{        
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "*", Method = "*")]
    Message Help(Message m);
}
```

Message from the inherited class:

```
public class WebHttpHelpPageMessage : Message
{
    ...

    protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("html");
        writer.WriteRaw("<head></head><body><p>Hi</p></body>");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

The result in the browser - XML, how to do it to be HTML?

Comment: its not that clear about your requirement but are you saying that, you browser displays xml and you want to display html instead?

Comment: Yes, that content-type="text/html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you already have got the xml what i can suggest you to do is create an xml object. And then, create xslt (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256069.aspx) as per you desire.

Then you can transform that xml in to HTML using xslt. It's easy that way and you have the control over how you want to display that.

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)

This is good enough if you follow this approach.